# Jsoup, how to get attribute

Tags: android

I got a html file like below:

```
   <a href="http://...123"><img src="http://...jpg?" border="0"/></a>

   <a href="http://...456">
              .
              .
              .
```

I want to get the attribute of href link and img src to a HashMap,

but several(not all) `<a href="">` tag do not go with `<img src="">` tag,

so how should i get the pare of attribute href link and img src to the HashMap?

if href link without img src, then abandon the line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the  tag which are not followed by  a  tag? or the other?
if its the other way you can try this
Take xpath as something like String path = "//a[@href]/img" and another like "//a[@href]".
Store the href tag value and next parse for the child nodes and if it contains the img tag parse it and store it as a key value pair.

Comment: yes, i want to store link and image to a HashMap,
so if the tag without image resource, abandon it.
the concept is like 'for(int i=0; i<htmlNodedata.size(); i++){if(link has image){hashMap.put(link, image)} else {continue;}}',but i'm new in Jsoup, so can you give me a sample with the condition above? thanks

Comment: well i didnt do HTML parsing in Jsoup but used HTML cleaner and did it by checking whether the tag has inner tag say in your example <img> and if it has we just showed the value to the user.